# PNG images look a jagged on IE, added bicubic style... no fix

Tags: internet-explorer, png

link: http://www.nationalpaymentcard.com/zipline/

I have completed the page but now whenever i load this page on IE i only get load issues with the pngs. Most importantly i cant get the logo to not be jagged. Its fine on all browsers except IE.

I have tried using -bicubic styles for the images but still no luck. Im hoping someone can help me figure this issue. I have also use kraken.io to compress my images but even after much compression the site still has its load issues on mobile browsers and on IE

Comment: Your images use the full-alpha transparency feature of PNG to reduce the jaggies.  Unfortunately as you have observed, IE doesn't support alpha-PNGs very well.  See the wikipedia page on PNG, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics in the section about Web browser support.  90 percent or more of that paragraph talks about the shortcomings of IE support and gives some suggestions about dealing with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image is too big (height 751px) and you are showing with a height of only 30px, apparently IE isn't as good as the other browsers scaling the image.

Try to edit the image with a good editor (ie GIMP) and scale it to the desired size. You will also save some bandwith.

Comment: I can confirm that eliminating scaling produces better image quality in IE for .png images. This was true even for minimally scaled images.